# Is there a quicker way to clear cache on Safari mobile?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mobile-safari

Is there a quicker way to clear cache in Safari on iPhone besides going to Settings -> Safari -> Clear Cache?

Answer (score 5):

I have found that reloading a Web page in Mobile Safari twice clears the cache for the current Web page. Simply press reload, wait for it to finish loading, then reload again.

Comment: nope that doesn't do it. some elements that are stored are not cleared by reloading the page.

Comment: Worked for me. It seems to work even when you hit refresh before it finishes loading.

Answer (score 2):

Regretfully, no.

(When I test my web code using Xcode's iOS Simulator, I find it easier to use the "Reset Content and Settings..." menu options rather than navigate into iOS's settings to clear the cache.)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way you can follow:

1. From the iPhone main menu, select "Settings" and then "Safari".
2. Scroll down to the bottom of the screen. There will be three options for you to choose from: "Clear History", "Clear Cookies", and "Clear Cache". You can simply clear all three by tapping each of them once and confirming the deletion
3. You can also clear your browsing history directly from the Safari browser. Start Safari and select "Bookmarks" at the bottom of the screen. Navigate to the history section  and select it.
4. Your internet history should then appear on the screen. You can then clear out the history by selecting "clear" at the bottom of the screen. It will then ask you to confirm "clear history".

I  hope this helps

Comment: Given that the questions explicitly asked for a faster way than "Settings -> Safari -> Clear Cache", this is probably not answer 'dev.e.loper' is looking for.

Comment: dev.e.loper is looking for a different way to *clear the cache*. Clearing the history is not the same.